# UnicodeDecodeError python django framework

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I have setup a project in my virtual environment. It was working fine before I update my windows 10. As of now, I'm running into an error related to the this

[image: UnidecodeError]

In my virtual environment, i have already install these libraries.

- python 3.8.1 (32-bit) - installed locally.
- asgiref==3.2.3
- certifi==2019.11.28
- cffi==1.14.0
- chardet==3.0.4
- cryptography==2.8
  Django==3.0.3
- django-appconf==1.0.3
- django-crispy-forms==1.8.1
  django-cryptography==1.0
- django-mssql-backend==2.7.0
- idna==2.8
- pycparser==2.19 
  -pyodbc==4.0.28
- pytz==2019.3
- requests==2.22.0
- six==1.14.0
- sqlparse==0.3.0
- urllib3==1.25.8
- django-adminlte3==0.1.2

The error started when I updated windows. Any idea how to solve this?
Things that I've tried

1. update using 64-bit python version
2. update my system locale

Comment: I think this is answer for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800697/django-sql-logging-as-utf-8-avoiding-unicodedecodeerror-while-settings-debug-t

Comment: i think my main problem is my db is corrupted. thus python couldn't fetch read the db to pass to view.